# Copy MathML into Word to use as equation

Tags: ms-word, mathml

I can successfully copy equations made using the insert equation tool in MS word (2013) to the clipboard in MathML format for use elsewhere.  However I mainly need to import into Word.  Is there a way to import MathML format equation into word to be used as equations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting MathMl , Tex or LaTex equation in MS word .docs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939050/inserting-mathml-tex-or-latex-equation-in-ms-word-docs)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you just tried to paste any MathML fragment copied from, for example, notepad?

It worked for me. Just Copy and paste the following first into notepad and, then, copy from notepad and paste it to word:

<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math>

Comment: Thanks I must have had the wrong headers when trying that before (now it works). Is there a way to convert the equations to OMML as the inserted MathML equations are now no longer editable (they may be edited by other people)? (note copying them in as OMML produces errors with eg sigma)

Comment: Word online supports displaying MathML, but not interpreting or inserting it (as of June 2018). You'll have to paste it in full client software, then it will show up in all versions, including browser-based.

Comment: Paste, then choose "text only", by `Ctrl` then (not plus) `T`