# i wanna insert two equal between three objects in python using sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

this is the code that can insert an equal between two objects:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import pprint
y =sp.Symbol('y')
x=sp.Eq((((y**2+2)*(y**3))/5)+3,3*(y**2))
pprint(x,use_unicode=True)
```

it's the result:

```
 3 ⎛ 2    ⎞           
y ⋅⎝y  + 2⎠          2
─────────── + 3 = 3⋅y 
     5
```

but if i wanna add another equal using another sp.Eq like this:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import pprint
y =sp.Symbol('y')
x=sp.Eq(sp.Eq((((y**2+2)*(y**3))/5)+3,3*(y**2)),0)
pprint(x,use_unicode=True)
```

the result is:

```
False
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to put a three = in the function like a=b=c i can make only a=b but i can't put the three =

Comment: I can read that from your question, but my questionis ‘why’ do you want to put _two_ = in the function? Is this because you hope to solve the equations (in which case while it’s obvious that y=0 is a solution to b=c it’s less obvious there’s a solution to a=c(=0) and certainly not with y=0 so your ‘equality’ doesn’t appear possible)?

Comment: I want to solve a rule with more than step so i want make more than = because then i want try to write it in a file docx

Comment: @MagdyRafeet are you trying to solve a system of equations [like this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%28%28%28y%5E2%2B2%29*%28y%5E3%29%29%2F5%29%2B3+%3D+3*%28y%5E2%29+%2C+3*%28y%5E2%29+%3D+0) ?

Comment: No i don't need the result but i want to write the form of equation because i want to put it in Microsoft word

Comment: Alright, in that case, you could print the formulas/equations you want in [MathML format](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html#mathml), and then copy the MathML string into Word [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25448431/827519). That should allow you to embed SymPy formulas into Word. Can you try that and see if it works ?

Comment: Okay I'll try. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `evaluate=False`:

```
In [7]: Eq(Eq(3, 4, evaluate=False), 2, evaluate=False)
Out[7]: 3 = 4 = 2
```